# Как получить сумму всех value?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть data и я пытаюсь получить сумму всех value, но получаю отдельно в массиве

```js
const data = [
{
  name: "june",
  projs: [
    {
      name: "proj1",
      value: 4
    },
    {
      name: "proj77",
      value: 2
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: "jule",
  projs: [
    {
      name: "proj33",
      value: 1
    },
    {
      name: "proj123",
      value: 3
    }
  ]
},
{
  name: "august",
  projs: [
    {
      name: "proj918",
      value: 2
    },
    {
      name: "proj13",
      value: 1
    }
  ]
}
];


const getMAxValue = (data) => {
  return data.map(val => val.projs.reduce((acc, next)  => acc.value + next.value),0)
}

console.log(getMAxValue(data));
```

Comment: `return data.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.projs.reduce((s, i) => s + i.value, 0), 0);`

Answer (score 3):

Метод `map()` создаёт новый массив с результатом вызова указанной функции для каждого элемента массива.

```js
const data = [{
    name: "june",
    projs: [{
        name: "proj1",
        value: 4
      },
      {
        name: "proj77",
        value: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "jule",
    projs: [{
        name: "proj33",
        value: 1
      },
      {
        name: "proj123",
        value: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "august",
    projs: [{
        name: "proj918",
        value: 2
      },
      {
        name: "proj13",
        value: 1
      }
    ]
  }
];


const getMAxValue = (data) => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let object of data) {
    sum += object.projs.reduce((acc, next) => acc.value + next.value);
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(getMAxValue(data));
```

Answer (score 3):

> получить сумма всех value

Предложу еще такой вариант...

```js
const data = [{
    name: "june",
    projs: [{
        name: "proj1",
        value: 4
      },
      {
        name: "proj77",
        value: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "jule",
    projs: [{
        name: "proj33",
        value: 1
      },
      {
        name: "proj123",
        value: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "august",
    projs: [{
        name: "proj918",
        value: 2
      },
      {
        name: "proj13",
        value: 1
      }
    ]
  }
];


const getMAxValue = data => (
  data.reduce((s, {projs}) => s + projs.reduce((s, {value}) => s + value, 0), 0)
)

console.log(getMAxValue(data));
```